# How to correctly use Mod 10^9+7

Tags: java, algorithm, modulo, largenumber

In Java, I need to calculate sum of squares of first n numbers i.e.

```
1^2 + 2^2+ 3^2+.....+n^2
```

which is

```
n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
```

OR

```
n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6
```

Then I need to calculate another value

```
n*(n-1/2)^2
```

As n is going to be very big answer can be "answer%M" where M is 10^9+7.

I am not able to understand at which point of calculation I should do operation %M. e.g.

```
n%M * (n+1)%M (2n+1)%M /  6
```

or

```
(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6)%M
```

Can you please help me here. Also in general please provide the guidelines for using %M;so that I can decide it next time onward.

Comment: This must have been asked before. It may be difficult to search for `10 ^ 9 + 7`. You may try `1000000007`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6)%M` is correct in theory and `n%M * (n+1)%M * (2n+1)%M / 6` is incorrect.

If `n` is large, the intermediate calculations of `(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6)` will overflow your integer type, so the first method is also unsatisfactory.

The general solution for computing `a*b/c % M` would be to compute the [modular inverse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularInverse.html) of `c` mod `M` (say `c'`) and then compute: `((a%M * b%M)%M * c')%M`

Here, it's a little simpler as you're dividing by a constant (6) and can find and strike out factors of 2 and 3 in the three terms. Something like this in pseudocode:

```
n1 := n
n2 := n+1
n3 := 2n+1
if n1 % 2 == 0 { n1 /= 2 } else { n2 /= 2 }
if n1 % 3 == 0 { n1 /= 3 } else if n2 % 3 == 0 { n2 /= 3 } else { n3 /= 3}
return (((n1 % M) * (n2 % M)) % M * (n3 % M)) % M
```

Comment: For simple constants, you can use wolfram alpha to compute this inverse. For example, [6^-1 mod 10^9+7](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E-1+mod+10%5E9%2B7) = 166666668.

Comment: why did you not do ..    else if n2 %2 ==0 (n2 /=2 } else {n3 /=2}   ....    any specific reason ?

Comment: ohh ..got it ..if  n%2 is not 0 then it is odd number so n+1 will surely even number. so  n2%2 will surely zero

Comment: `n3` is always odd. Exactly one of `n1` and `n2` is even. Exactly one of `n1`, `n2` and `n3` is divisible by 3.

Comment: If your modulo is prime, and it is in the case of 10^9+7, then you can use the formula c^(M-2) mod M to compute modular inverse of c mod M, which can be easily done with fast pow.

Comment: The question is tagged java, one and a half nits: 1) M² exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`: for the first multiplication to be evaluated to `long`, one of the operands of better be `long`. 2) *If* `n` does *not* exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, there is no need to apply the modulus to each factor - just be sure to use long for `n2` and `n3` (*including* their computation) (`long n2 = n+1L, n3 = n+n2;`).

Answer (score 0):

Division by modulo can't be made by / operator: `(a/b) % M != ((a % M)/(b % M)) % M`, so you need to take modulo only at the end:

```
(n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6) % M
```

For more information read [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). And don't forget to use `BigInteger` class for calculations with realy big numbers.